# MarkLogic Data Hub cluster upgrade

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

We are looking at upgrading our v4.1 Data Hub to v5.2 on our 2 node ML v9.x cluster ( upgrading server v9.x to v10.x ) and need to understand the mechanism for the Data Hub upgrade process.  For the Server, the upgrade of a cluster is straight forward.

What is the process for upgrading the data hub component of a cluster?  With the server component of a cluster you can upgrade one server, and the cluster management does the rest. But with a data hub the upgrade is quite manual from v4.1 to v5.2.

Data Hubs are "anchored" into the server, but are upgraded separately. Will all instances of the data hub that are on a cluster ( i.e. data hub on server 1 and data hub on server 2 of the cluster ) be upgraded when you upgrade the data hub on server 1 ( which has the security database ) , or do we need to upgrade each data hub installation on both server 1 and server 2 individually in the cluster?

Any assistance appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data hub functionality is driven by the contents of your modules database, which is shared across all nodes in your cluster. When you do the update for one node, it will update the contents of your modules database and all nodes will see that.

Comment: To clarify - should I then follow the same process of a server cluster upgrade of upgrading the Data Hub on the node that has the security database on it, and then that will update all the other nodes?

Comment: You can update the data hub code from any node that has access to the modules database. Doing it once will update the data hub code for all. It's just like updating your application code, but different from upgrading MarkLogic itself.